# Error while parsing PIG-XML

Tags: xml, apache-pig

I am trying to parse xml using pig (version 0.12), but getting below error:

**Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: 
 Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]**

My XML file is as below:

```
<CATALOG>
<BOOK>
<TITLE>Hadoop Defnitive Guide</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>Tom White</AUTHOR>
<COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CLOUDERA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>24.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>2012</YEAR>
</BOOK>
<BOOK>
<TITLE>Programming Pig</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>Alan Gates</AUTHOR>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Horton Works</COMPANY>
<PRICE>30.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>2013</YEAR>
</BOOK>
</CATALOG>
```

Practcing from: http://hadoopgeek.com/apache-pig-xml-parsing-xpath/

Below is the script:

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar

DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();

A =  LOAD '/hadoop_books.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('BOOK') as (x:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'BOOK/AUTHOR'), XPath(x, 'BOOK/PRICE');


dump B;
```

Kindly help

```
I have kept .xml file in hadoop root directory
```

Comment: you must make a dir name xmls and then add hear the 'hadoop_books.xml' file then try to run.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want parens in your DEFINE statement:

```
    DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath;
```

You can also debug by removing the `DEFINE` and referencing the UDF directly:

```
    B = FOREACH A GENERATE 
        org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath(x, 'BOOK/AUTHOR'),
        org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath(x, 'BOOK/PRICE');
```

If that doesn't work, then `piggybank.jar` is not found on your classpath and you may need to give the full path to the jar.